# Cross Site Request Forgery protection in Django - a better explanation?

Tags: django, csrf

I've just completed part 4 of the Django 1.4 tutorial and I'm sure they just chucked CSRF and generic views in to confuse the hell out of me.

Okay, so generic views I get now, but I don't understand what is happening with CSRF protection.

This is what I think is happening: the CSRF token is a hash/key generated by modules used in the app and a logged in user if logged in. The token is somehow sent with a POST method form to the receiving view which again generates the hash and compares it with the one sent with the form to make sure nobody has snooped in? Have I got this completely wrong?

Having used the rest of the Django manual during the tutorial this is by far the most confusing manual page I have read.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say, you understand it exactly. It's *somehow* added by calling the csrf tag `{% csrf_token %}` which renders a hidden input with the token generated server side. Essentially, you must at least render the page to get this token / thus validate your form post.

Comment: Well it looks like I managed to squeeze that doc page into two sentences, which would have been better for someone following the tutorial I guess. Thank you for the confirmation though, needed that at least.

Comment: Are you referring to the docs on CSRF? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/ I can see why the tutorial would simply brush over the concept.. it would be confusing to dive into it.

Answer (score 2):

It's confusing because it addresses a subtle vulnerability with web browsers.

Let's say we have two sites: site.com and evil.com. Then the owner of evil.com can, if he knows the structure of the site.com website (which is easy if he can use it), set up a form targeting it.

```
<form action="http://target.com/my_account/_delete" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Click Here for candy"></input>
</form>
```

Anyone clicking it and logged into site.com will instantly trigger the action linked to (in this case, destroying their own account).

The idea of a csrf token is that the legitimate form looks like this:

```
<form action="http://target.com/my_account/_delete" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="AEyaF8af8AIHJFA0L"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Don't click this unless absolutely sure!"></input>
</form>
```

and because this value is user specific, and only known by and shown on the website, the users are now safe, and can't delete their account without going through the proper page first, as any page from the attacker would not know this value.

Hopefully this is clearer.

Comment: So, actually less to do with snooping and more to do with phishing then? I think my issue with the docs is that it's not entirely clear that one part is used for transmitting and there is another half for picking up the pieces at the other end. Also, my own fault but I was zipping through this part of the tutorial and with the hidden field being stuck in it's own div it didn't look immediately like the token was part of the form.

Comment: Yeah, it's to authenticate that all requests originate from legitimate pages.